# Declarar namespaces no XML em classes importadas por WSDL (jax-ws)

Tags: java, xml, wsdl, jax-ws, xml-namespaces

Estou no desenvolvimento de uma aplicação de WebService utilizando o jax-ws. Nesse modelo após importar o WSDL a IDE gera as classes que serão utilizadas nas trocas de informação. Porém ao criar o objeto e passar como parâmetro recebo a mensagem doo servidor:

> undeclared namespace prefix 'x' at offset 143 of http://urlexample.com

Quando faço o marshalling do objeto para verificar o XML se está correto recebo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ans:solicitacaoProcedimentoWS xmlns:ans="http://exemplo" 
 xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ans:cabecalho>
   ...
</ans:cabecalho>
   ...
```

porém devo informar esse namespace no cabeçalho da seguinte maneira:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:ans="http://exemplo" xmlns:xd="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
   <ans:solicitacaoProcedimentoWS>
      ...
   </ans:solicitacaoProcedimentoWS>
      ...
```

Abaixo o código que converte o objeto em XML:

```
 public static String converteBeanXML(Object bean) {
    try {
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(bean.getClass());
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(bean, writer);

        return writer.toString();
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        escreveLogErro(ex.getMessage(), "SisUtil.converteBeanXML()");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Como devo fazer essa declaração de namespaces no header do XML se todas as classes foram geradas quando importei o WSDL?

Comment: Poste o código em que você monta esse XML

Comment: @Marquezani era isso mesmo?

Comment: Nesse trecho você gera o XML puro sem o envelope SOAP. Você tem o código que gera o envelope SOAP? Poste ele por favor

Answer (score 0):

No arquivo **package-info.java** (gerado na importação do WSDL), altera a anotação @XmlSchema para ficar da seguinte forma:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.ans.gov.br/padroes/tiss/schemas", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns = {@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix="sch", namespaceURI="http://www.ans.gov.br/padroes/tiss/schemas")})
```

Caso use o Apache CXF, a solução é um pouco diferente:

```
final Client c = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
final Map<String, String> nsMap = new HashMap<>();
nsMap.put("sch", "http://www.ans.gov.br/padroes/tiss/schemas");
c.getRequestContext().put("soap.env.ns.map", nsMap);
```